# Linux webfilter with LDAP SSO authentication

Tags: linux, active-directory, squid, single-sign-on, privoxy

I'm looking for a self-made linux proxy/webfilter server and stumbled upon several
products. (squidguard, dansguardian, ..) I found Privoxy the most appealing. Now
I went searching on the internet for any help on configuring a squid proxy server together with privoxy and using Windows Active Directory LDAP NTLM SSO authentication.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Web Filtering On Squid 3 With QuintoLabs Content Security 1.4 And Windows Active Directory Integration](http://www.howtoforge.com/web-filtering-on-squid-3-with-quintolabs-content-security-1.4-and-windows-active-directory-integration-p2)

This way you get SSO on Squid with Kerberos and extensive web filtering with qlproxy as ICAP server.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.